# Log deleted files when button is clicked? Log all files (deleted and undeleted)

Tags: c#

I am writing an application to delete file on a test folder that are over 6 months, the application works fine as I have tested it, I wanted to create a log file to keep track of the name of the deleted files for audit purpose.

but with the scirpt below it does record all the files (deleted and undeleted), all I need is just record the date and time and the name of the deleted files.

Thank you

**Script Below:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Delete_PDF_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string strLogText;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            // check the number of file in the CPS directory on S drive
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\"); // @"S:\CPS Papers\"
            this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
            textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        }

        // delete button to delete files over 6 months from CPS folder
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\"); //S:\CPS Papers  test C:\test\

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);

                if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
                    fi.Delete();

                // Create a writer and open the file: //C:\test\log
                System.IO.StreamWriter log;

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\test\\log\\logfile.txt"))
                {
                    log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\test\\log\\logfile.txt");
                }
                else
                {
                    log = File.AppendText("C:\\test\\log\\logfile.txt");
                }

                // Write to the file:
                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); 
                log.WriteLine(strLogText);
                log.WriteLine();
                log.WriteLine();

                // Close the stream:
                log.Close();

            }
        }

        // Exit button
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or you could just use a single line of powershell....

Answer (score 0):

Replace you delete code with this one:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\"); //S:\CPS Papers  test C:\test\

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
            //if (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
            if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
            {
                fi.Delete();
                using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\\test\\log\\logfile.txt"))
                {
                    writer.Write("File: " + file + " deleted at : "+DateTime.Now);
                    writer.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there,thank you for a quick reply, I have just tried it its brilliant log, it still showing the files that are not deleted as they are less than 6 months and its showing them as deleted File: C:\test\Plumbing Covering Letter.docx deleted at : 20/04/2013 10:35:37File: C:\test\alger à une certaine époque.docx deleted at : 20/04/2013 10:35:37----------------------------------------------------
File: C:\test\cover letter.docx deleted at : 20/04/2013 10:35:37---

Comment: This seems to be impossible because code is inside your condition `fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom logging as you are doing I would recommend that you use a good library like [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). Why reinvent the wheel?  I know that it has a small learning curve time but once you get to know you you can easily integrate it in any new projects.

By just adding a config section to your app.config as given [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) and a few lines of code you should be ready to go.

A good tutorial on Log4Net can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)

Comment: thank you, will check it up later, I have seen few recommandation on the net for Log4Net.

Comment: Great! I have been working on it for six months and still wish that i had started using it earlier.